# Why did Nebula say Thanos isn't a liar?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, dialogue, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, Nebula says this:

> My father is many things. A liar is not one of them.

I want to know if he never lied to Nebula, or was she just saying that to make sure he doesn't doubt her?

Thanos clearly lied before, for example, when he promised Eitri that he would spare the dwarves if he made the Gauntlet for him, but after he got it he just killed them all!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> My father is many things. A liar is not one of them.

### Apparently, this is true.

I can't find a single instance of Thanos *lying* about anything.

Certainly, his motivations and reasoning are flawed but he holds his beliefs *honestly* and he's ruthless and powerful enough to follow through without the need to lie about it,.

As for the example you gave, **Thanos did not promise to spare the dwarves**.

> Eitri: 300 dwarves lived on this ring. **I thought if I did what he asked, they'd be safe**. I made what he wanted. A device capable of harnessing the power of the stones. Then he killed everyone anyway. All except me.

Turns out Eitri should have *asked*....his assumption was wrong.

Comment: He does, though, tell Gamora that he never taught her to lie. Can one be good enough to teach others to lie if they themselves are not an accomplished liar?

Comment: But as you state "he didn't teach her to lie". She seems to have learned that by herself.

Comment: @KennethK. Maybe he meant that if he actually was a liar, he would have taught her and she would be good at it

Comment: @Paulie_D But after that quote "I never taught you to lie", Thanos told Gamora "this is why you aren't a good liar". Why should a non-accomplished-liar person say this?

Comment: @aminabzz - That logic does not follow. He is just making a straight forward statement about a fact as he sees it. And, he is arrogant enough to think she could not successfully accomplish anything that was not originated by him. Here is a real world analogy. My father never taught me to sail. Therefore, I am not a good sailor. As a matter of fact, neither of us would make good sailors. He was also never a soldier. So, I did not have the advantage of learning by example how to be a soldier. What he did know, he taught me. Other things, I learned on my own.

Comment: @DeanF. But many people can read Thanos' quote in this way: "If I had taught you to lie, you would become a good liar.". In other words: "You aren't a good liar / You are a bad liar, because you didn't learn it from me.".

Comment: @aminabzz - Actually, that is my point exactly. Thanos is stating exactly what you are implying he meant. I think that is a near perfect interpretation. Nothing she does can she be good at unless it comes from him (in his mind). Everything she is good at is his creation and his alone. He is undermining her. But, this does not mean that he himself is a liar. Just, that he did not teach her. He would probably think she was the best liar even if he was not a good liar if he had taught her. You know...Those who can not do, teach. Those who can not teach, teach gym. 

Comment: @aminabzz - Remember, Thanos is supremely arrogant. But, he is not vainly boastful.